# What happens under the hood when we define a type alias with a type variable in Elm

Tags: elm

Suppose we define a type alias say `Message` as:

```
type alias Message a =
{ code : String
, body : a
}
```

And later define a function `readMessage` as:

```
readMessage : Message () -> String
readMessage message =
...
```

The above example is from Elm tutorial and book says:

> This function takes Message with an empty body. This is not the same
>   as any value, just an empty one.

Can someone please elaborate what exactly happens in above scenario and how compiler handles it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really want to see the internal compiler representation of that, I think what's important here is the difference between `any value` and `empty value`.

`Message a` is a parametrized type with 1 parameter. You can read it as a template, e.g. wherever lowercase `a` appears in the definition of the `Message` it will be substituted with the concrete type (String, Int, etc).

So this is how function should look like if we want it to take a `Message` with `String` body:

```
readMessage : Message String -> String
readMessage message =
```

What happens here is that the type of `body` field is no longer an `a` but a `String` (`a` is substituted with `String`):

```
{ code : String
, body : String
}
```

The value of nothing (aka `void` or `unit`) in Elm is encoded as `()`. That's why a `Message` with empty body value looks like this:

```
{ code : String
, body : ()
}
```

But when we simply don't care about the body value we can just take a `Message` with `any` value:

```
readMessage : Message a -> String
readMessage message =
```

The lowercase `a` can be any lowercase string, we can make it more readable like this:

```
readMessage : Message any -> String
readMessage message =
```

But then we cannot really read message body, because we don't know the type of it (so we don't know how to read it).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The type `Message ()` is an alias for the following record:

```
{ code : String
, body : ()
}
```

where the `()` type denotes a tuple without any items (also known as *null tuple*). There is only one value of such type and it is also written `()`.

Now, when we want to omit some field in a record, we cannot just not specify it – that would make the compiler rightly mad, see also [The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare). We need to tell the compiler that the value can be omitted.

One way we could do it is to use the [`Maybe`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe) type but if we made a list of messages that would allow us to include the body in some messages and omit it in others. This might not be what we want.

The alternative is to parametrize the `Message` type as you are doing in the question. This will allow us to have a messages with `String` bodies when reading the message, and with a different body type when we are not interested in the body.

In this case, we need to consider what the body type should be. While we could use an empty `String`s for messages with omitted bodies, they would be easily confused with messages with empty bodies. We could also use `Bool` but then we would need to decide if we want to use `True` or `False` for the omitted value. Finally, we can use the *null tuple*; since it only has one possible value it is ideal for us.

There is actually one more possibility: we could create a `type alias MessageWithoutBody = { code: String }`. This is cleaner in some cases (especially when you need to omit more fields) but can be more verbose as you need to duplicate all the fields you want to keep.